# Why is Python 2.7 executing instead of 3.5?

Tags: python, macos

in ~/.bash_profile, I have the following:

```
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH

PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

When I type in `python --version` in Terminal, I get `2.7.10`.

Any idea why 3.5 is not executing?

-- UPDATE ---
I have updated the .bash_profile with:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Then ran `~/.bash_profile`. `echo $PATH` shows the following:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5:/Users/myuser/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

When I try to execute `python --version`, now I get this:

```
-bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/python: cannot execute binary file
```

I tried reverting .bash_profile back so I can at least run Python 2.7 again but that didn't work. I still get the same cannot execute binary error.

To fix all of this, I did `brew install python`. Still same error.

But `python3 --version` works.

Comment: Have you done `source ~/.bash_profile` after updating the PATH in there?  Does an executable named `python` actually exist in that directory?  What does `echo $PATH` tell you?

Comment: Are you sure you have switched to the bash shell. You could be using another shell you can check with this command env | grep SHELL

Comment: `python3`, by default there is no `python` in that directory unless you explicitly create the symlink.

Comment: Environment variable `SHELL` (print its value more simply with `echo "$SHELL"`) doesn't tell you what the _current_ shell is - it only ever tells you what the current user's _default_ shell is.

Comment: Make sure that you can invoke your Python 3 binary _by its full path_ from your current shell, and take it from there. If you install Python 3 via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), for instance (macOS comes with Python 2.7.10, as of 10.12), it is installed as `/usr/local/bin/python3`. As an aside: once a variable is marked as exported in Bash, subsequent modifications do not change that status, so your 2nd `export PATH` command is unnecessary. (In most cases, the 1st `export` is unnecessary too).

Comment: Use the command python3.5

Comment: Updated the question based on comments.

Comment: You should use `python3` command, don't try to mess with `python`, which may be needed by the system to run python2 code